# AEM 6.1 LESS version

Tags: less, aem

I've have been searching and digging around but for the life of me I can not find which version of LESS is included with AEM 6.1 (or 6.2). I know that CQ (AEM) 5.6.1 uses LESS 1.3.3 but I'd like to know if the version was updated with AEM 6.

Comment: We are moving to AEM6.2 and I confirmed it also uses Less 1.7.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

-The compilation of the LESS logic is done on the server side using Rhino (a Javascript compiler for Java) and LESS

-If you go to your Felix console and look under Bundles you should find one called "Adobe Granite UI Clientlibs - Less Compiler(com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.compiler.less)".

-To get to the JAR file for this bundle you will need to note the number next to it in the console.
(In my case it is bundle number 193.)

-Assuming the bundle number is 193, on your file system go to "/crx/quickstart/launchpad/felix/bundle193/version0.0"

-If you open bundle.jar you will find version of LESS.
(For extracting JAR file you can use jd-gui.exe jar extractor.)
-In AEM 6.1 the current version of LESS is-1.7.5

Comment: Thank you! I tried digging into the Jar, but all I found was that it used less, I couldn't find a version number anywhere. Ver 1.7.5 is good to know.

Comment: And now I see what I was missing. Followed your steps (which I had done previously); I was mistaking 1.7.5 for the version of Rhino, not LESS.

Comment: Checked on my AEM 6.5 and sadly the default is still seemingly LESS 1.7.5, if it ain't broke don't fix it?! 

Well lots of stuff being missed out on, here's the LESS release notes on what's been added these past 8 YEARS: 
https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

The version of LESS is included with AEM 6.1 is -1.7.5

To get to the JAR file for this bundle you will need to note the number next to it in the console in my case it is bundle number 74.

Assuming the bundle number is 74, on your file system go to "/crx/quickstart/launchpad/felix/bundle74/version0.0"